# Laravel Framework, AngularJS - Not Routing

Tags: angularjs, laravel, routes

I am trying to develop an application with Laravel Framework and AngularJS. However, I have the "routing" problem. I have the file "Master.blade.php". But the AngularJS "html" and "controller" files do not appear.

[My Local Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeoDu.jpg)

- webpack.mix.js [not problem js and sass files]

```html
const { mix } = require('laravel-mix');

mix.scripts([
    'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/bootstrap.js',
    'node_modules/angular/angular.js',
    'node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.js',
    'node_modules/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
    'resources/assets/js/app.js',
    'resources/assets/js/controllers/authController.js'
], 'public/assets/js/app.js')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/assets/css/app.css');
```

- web.php - Laravel routing

```html
<?php

Route::get('/app', function () {
    return view('layouts.master');
});
```

- Master.blade.php

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html ng-app="bildirioApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Bildirio</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/app.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('assets/js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

- App.js

```js
/* This is the main file where Angular is defined */
var bildirioApp = angular.module('bildirioApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies']);

bildirioApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $routeProvider.when('/login', {
            templateUrl : 'resources/views/auth/login.html',
            controller  : 'authController',
        });

        $routeProvider.otherwise('/');

    }
]);
```

- authController.js

```js
bildirioApp.controller('authController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

}]);
```

- login.html

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-3 well">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <form name="loginForm" ng-submit="doLogin(loginForm)">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" ng-model="login.username" required placeholder="Enter your email address">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" ng-model="login.password" required placeholder="Enter your password">
            </div>

            <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="save" value="Login">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try placing the login.html file in the `public` directory rather than `resources` directory

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem you are facing is that your `login.html` file is not found.

When you are setting your template to

`templateUrl : 'resources/views/auth/login.html'`

your server is actually looking for

`{app_root_folder}/public/resources/views/auth/login.html`

which, of course, does not exist. That is because Angular does not have access to anything but the `public` folder and specific routes you define.

If you looked at the Network section of your browser's Developer Tools you will probably see a 404 error.

There are 2 ways you can fix this.

**Option 1** - Create a route that serves the `login.html` file.

First, change your `App.js` routing to:

```
 $routeProvider
            .when('/login', {
                templateUrl : 'login/getView',
                controller  : 'authController',
            });
```

Then, add the corresponding route in `web.php` which will serve the `login.html` file:

```
Route::get('/app', function () {
    return view('layouts.master');
});
Route::get('/login/getView', function () {
    return view('auth.login');
});
```

This, hopefully solves your problem. If not - monitor the Network requests in the Developer Tools to see if the `login.html` is found or not. Also make sure all other files are actually loaded correctly (i.e App.js).

**Option 2** - Move your `login.html` to the public folder (not recommended)

You can move the `login.html` into the `public` folder (`public/resources/views/auth/login.html`).

This is NOT my preferred way of doing it since it breaks your MVC pattern.

I usually like to have all my view files in the `resources/views` folder and not split them between `resources/views` and `public`.

Also, when they are in the `resources/views` folder you can use `.blade` files so serve to Angular. This way you can do server-side rendering before it reaches Angular (i.e `login.blade.php`).

Hope this helps!